Why does my pycharm terminal is failing to start
I've been having issues with the terminal in PyCharm recently it always gives me this error message:
Cannot open Local
Failed to start [powershell.exe, -NoExit, -ExecutionPolicy, Bypass, -File, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\plugins\terminal\shell-integrations\powershell\powershell-integration.ps1] in C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\pythonProject, [columns=161, rows=12], envs={CommonProgramFiles=>C:\Program Files\Common Files, =::=>::\, FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=>Default, USERDOMAIN=>DESKTOP-UI792GH, ProgramData=>C:\ProgramData, COMPUTERNAME=>DESKTOP-UI792GH, OneDriveCommercial=>C:\Users\asus\OneDrive - International Information Technology University, SystemDrive=>C:, IJ_RESTARTER_LOG=>C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2024.2\log\restarter.log, OneDriveConsumer=>C:\Users\asus\OneDrive, OneDrive=>C:\Users\asus\OneDrive - International Information Technology University, CommonProgramFiles(x86)=>C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, TMP=>C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp, TEMP=>C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp, VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=>C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\, ProgramFiles=>C:\Program Files, windir=>C:\WINDOWS, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=>DESKTOP-UI792GH, PyCharm Community Edition=>C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\bin;, PROCESSOR_LEVEL=>6, ComSpec=>C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=>12, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=>AMD64, OS=>Windows_NT, EFC_11668=>1, JETBRAINS_INTELLIJ_COMMAND_END_MARKER=>mcNkZuvsa73YFEdO8heyjV04N8vnV5MkXIVYFDfZYaKCASgpAAYtst2VMfOFRpn8, EnableLog=>INFO, ProgramFiles(x86)=>C:\Program Files (x86), PSModulePath=>C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules, PATHEXT=>.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=>Intel64 Family 6 Model 141 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel, APPDATA=>C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming, ACSetupSvcPort=>23210, RlsSvcPort=>22112, LOCALAPPDATA=>C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local, SystemRoot=>C:\WINDOWS, HOMEPATH=>\Users\asus, JEDITERM_SOURCE=>C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/Scripts/activate.ps1, TERMINAL_EMULATOR=>JetBrains-JediTerm, LOGONSERVER=>\\DESKTOP-UI792GH, SESSIONNAME=>Console, IGCCSVC_DB=>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAqbskprLcEUirO6fdagZJVgQAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACcqrx2cOfxrLXDAgEcxO9UcKqoHrkxx+Pkc0scGzo32AAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAB8XTU4p3yRXeLABSjbooS/tpcZvq1AcqI5kki53CWv12AAAABF3DKEpR9wBeYn0uJYh4Uu8LntGr2o3Ao4DJa7K0aOrXHgTLzVRmecZc3e9A0Rq6sduRUJoNTbJvZqgBcrtRpK5DoF766+J89YYw9ToDdBp/fEQX118WYk8febvSX1k2dAAAAAwvKlUmib2UFScHW6GnFFjfkRg0wPU7zCyj5mpqJKsIOnDrw9ZOqiiy+Uy7GvY94JHKpPuCR2w/qzyniCJCBqhg==, HOMEDRIVE=>C:, DriverData=>C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData, FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=>Internet Explorer, Path=>C:\Users\asus\Desktop\aircrack-ng-1.7-win\aircrack-ng-1.7-win\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;"C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe";C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\bin;, PUBLIC=>C:\Users\Public, PT8HOME=>C:\Program Files\Cisco Packet Tracer 8.2.2, ACSvcPort=>17532, IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY=>C:\Users\asus, PROCESSOR_REVISION=>8d01, USERPROFILE=>C:\Users\asus, ALLUSERSPROFILE=>C:\ProgramData, USERNAME=>asus, CommonProgramW6432=>C:\Program Files\Common Files, ProgramW6432=>C:\Program Files, ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=>1, TERM_SESSION_ID=>ed4df495-a2ac-4e5c-bd92-fc2c33b3b393}


See IDE log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details. 


I tried reinstalling PyCharm and Python, but it didn't solve the problem. I also attempted to modify the PATH in my Windows environment, but that didn’t help either.(https://i.sstatic.net/nSVm6vPN.png)
Tried to tinker with interpreter but didn't get anything. I am still new to codding but terminal was working for a quite a while before and I can't think of anything that might have caused this problem
Edited:
Sorry for mess of a question I was sleep deprived and quite frankly don't know English that well(It is my third language).
I was able to manually start the terminal(with debug button), but the problem persists. I updated PyCharm, as recommended by Charles Knell, and even reinstalled PowerShell, but the issue remains. When using the new terminal(beta) in the updated version of PyCharm, the error message disappeared but with it ability to type in it too
If your interested I used this code to manually activate it:
$script:THIS_PATH = $myinvocation.mycommand.path
$script:BASE_DIR = Split-Path (Resolve-Path "$THIS_PATH/..") -Parent

function global:deactivate([switch] $NonDestructive) {
    if (Test-Path variable:_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH) {
        $env:PATH = $variable:_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
        Remove-Variable "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH" -Scope global
    }

    if (Test-Path function:_old_virtual_prompt) {
        $function:prompt = $function:_old_virtual_prompt
        Remove-Item function:\_old_virtual_prompt
    }

    if ($env:VIRTUAL_ENV) {
        Remove-Item env:VIRTUAL_ENV -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    if (!$NonDestructive) {
        # Self destruct!
        Remove-Item function:deactivate
        Remove-Item function:pydoc
    }
}

function global:pydoc {
    python -m pydoc $args
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate -nondestructive

$VIRTUAL_ENV = $BASE_DIR
$env:VIRTUAL_ENV = $VIRTUAL_ENV

New-Variable -Scope global -Name _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH -Value $env:PATH

$env:PATH = "$env:VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts;" + $env:PATH
if (!$env:VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT) {
    function global:_old_virtual_prompt {
        ""
    }
    $function:_old_virtual_prompt = $function:prompt

    if ("" -ne "") {
        function global:prompt {
            # Add the custom prefix to the existing prompt
            $previous_prompt_value = & $function:_old_virtual_prompt
            ("() " + $previous_prompt_value)
        }
    }
    else {
        function global:prompt {
            # Add a prefix to the current prompt, but don't discard it.
            $previous_prompt_value = & $function:_old_virtual_prompt
            $new_prompt_value = "($( Split-Path $env:VIRTUAL_ENV -Leaf )) "
            ($new_prompt_value + $previous_prompt_value)
        }
    }
}


This unformatted mess is hardly a question - please clean up the the example (and perhaps fix the several spelling errors while you're at it). Have you read the error message? It seems fairly clear at the start? I.e. "Failed to start [powershell.exe" - have you looked at why it might not be able to start powershell? And perhaps disable the plugin it mentions "plugins\terminal\shell-integrations\powershell"?

@Grismar The question definitely needs an edit, but there's no need to be rude about it.

Let us know if you can start powershell at a command prompt. powershell needs to be available on your system.  Also, I recommend that you upgrade to the latest community version of pycharm.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried my best to edit my question and will appreciate feedback. Will try to give more thought  in the future if I will have questions again!

Above you show us your environment variables. The list does not appear to be complete as it is missing the "Path" variable. If it really is missing "Path", that's a problem.

Make sure that you are using the correct version of pycharm community. There is one for ARM64 and different one for x64.
To check whether your PC is running an ARM64 architecture, you can follow these steps:

The download links for the latest version of python community is at the bottom of the following page: pycharm downloads
